# VideoPlayer when playing video after 10 seconds stops playing

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

I`m using NavRecoder and after record I need to show a video but when I play video after 10 seconds, the video stops images and audio.

```
video.SetTargetAudioSource(0,video_a);
video.url = path;
video.Play();
```

I need to see all the videos but I see only 10 seconds.

Comment: I had the same problem while using too large resolution image. Try decreasing the resolution and play it again to see if that would help. You can set the resolution in the video clip settings.

Comment: resolution set 640x640

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using [BetterVideoPlayer](https://github.com/halilozercan/BetterVideoPlayer), written in Kotlin here, as this may rectify your issue.